# Xamarin Emulator Window Issues

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

So today I discovered a very interesting bug. If I have my dell docking station plugged into my laptop, and run any form of an android emulator from Visual Studio Xamarin live player, the window is a blank box. This isn't just on my machine, this affects several developers with the same docking station, but not those with the older dell docking stations. We were able to determine this issue because it was similar to this with RingCentral software:

https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5305

It's unproductive for me to use just my laptop so I'm wondering if there is a fix/workaround.

For debugging purposes, I followed all of Microsoft's troubleshooting guides including matching their recommended BIOS settings. I even ran Process Monitor and did not find anything out of the ordinary. It appeared as everything was running fine but just couldn't display in the window.

Comment: https://aka.ms/live-player-report-issue